# OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, out-of-memory

In my application a txt file is being processed using apache camel, application reads whole file into string using exchange object & performs delimeter adding on each line & writes into to the file as a whole string using exchange object of apache camel. I am getting below OutOfMemoryError. ***I observed this exception is occuring after file processing is completed by exchange object & when it is supposed to move the file to another folder(endpoint)* **.

*My application has 16GB heap space support*. File size before processing is 685MB & after adding delimiter it may increase 200 MB extra.
Can anyone help me here? Thank you in advance.

```
from("file:<filepath>/processed/INPUT?filter=#fileFilter&delay=120000&exclusiveReadLockStrategy=#fileReadLockStrategy&delete=true&autoCreate=true")
                    .threads(10, 10)
                    .process(fileProcessor).log("Came out of file processor")
                    .recipientList(header(DESTIONATION_PATH));
```

Its a simple route which read file from INPUT folder & fileProcessor processes the file contents by adding delimter in it. DESTIONATION_PATH is the path where the file will be placed. I can see that it is printing log "Came out of file processor" , below Exception is coming when file is about to send to the destination folder.

```
Error has occurred: 
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-x01btadmdts3a-vsi-uat-dbs-com-1586519346908-0-4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1842) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:173) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:133) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:157) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ThreadsProcessor$ProcessCall.run(ThreadsProcessor.java:87) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
    Suppressed: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-x01btadmdts3a-vsi-uat-dbs-com-1586519346908-0-4]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
    ***Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit***
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toInputStream(IOConverter.java:198)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverterOptimised.convertTo(IOConverterOptimised.java:55)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.OptimisedTypeConverter.convertTo(OptimisedTypeConverter.java:63)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:299)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:188)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:115)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:333)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:305)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:169)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:80)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:173)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:133)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:157)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ThreadsProcessor$ProcessCall.run(ThreadsProcessor.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toInputStream(IOConverter.java:198) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverterOptimised.convertTo(IOConverterOptimised.java:55) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.OptimisedTypeConverter.convertTo(OptimisedTypeConverter.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:299) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:188) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:115) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:333) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:305) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:169) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:173) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:133) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:157) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ThreadsProcessor$ProcessCall.run(ThreadsProcessor.java:87) [camel-core-2.24.1.jar!/:2.24.1]
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. It sounds like you have a route which is using too much memory, causing the whole thing to crash. It would be helpful to see what your route looks like (either the XML or Java DSL). We may have suggestions based off that. It's hard to read a stack trace to determine what your existing code does and how it can be improved.

Comment: @AdamHawkes, Thank you for your response. Routes are based on Java DSL.

Comment: Great, you really need to include that RouteBuilder Java DSL into your question. Nobody can help you until you do that.

Comment: @AdamHawkes I have added the Java DSL route code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering late here. I was able to resolve above issue.
When I looked at logs carefully it was failing in the standard java class "StringCoding.java".

***Culprit in my code was below 2 lines:***

```
String content = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class); 
//Add deleimters in each line content string & write back the whole string in file.
//derive new content string from original content
exchange.getOut().setBody(content);// Camel stores content in String & sends it via route using character array.
```

***Analysis:***

Java stores string as a character array in behind the scene. As per logic we were adding some delimeters in each line.
I observed that (number of characters in original file + number of delimiters added) was > Integer.MAX_VALUE.
So, here the java was failing to store the whole string in to character array & camel was not able put the file 
in the destination folder path. This happened because the number of characters in modified file went beyond maximum integer size.

***Solution:***

```
File contentFile = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
//Process the contentFile as file line by line & write the records back in file.
exchange.getOut().setBody(contentFile);// Camel stores content in File & sends it via route using InputStream.
```

I kept above code & it worked we didn't see OutofMemory issue as no where array is used by camel while sending file via route.

Thank you for reading. Happy Coding...!!!